# What self-image do most people have?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, self

There seem to be a lot of studies about the influence of self-image on our psychology, but I've been wondering: Is there research on what type of self-image (positive, negative) most people have? Do people in Western countries tend to have a positive or a negative self-image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Short answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-verification_theory#Tension_with_self-enhancement):

> ... on the balance, most people tend to view themselves positively.

Longer answer:

Not much is clear about [self-image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-image).  One thing that is clear is that self-image is not one thing.  In the research literature, it can refer to a conglomerate of fairly independent / mildly correlated constructs, such as body image, self-schema, self-valuation, self-esteem, self-perceived physical attractiveness, self-worth, etc...  That is to say, one can score positively on some of these measures and negatively on others, with little relationship between the scores.

Culture may indeed [play a role as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority#Cultural_differences):

> More recent research investigating self-esteem in other countries
>   suggests that illusory superiority depends on culture. Some studies
>   indicate that East Asians tend to underestimate their own abilities in
>   order to improve themselves and get along with others.

The uncertainty between positive and negative self-image is underscored by the existence of both an [above-average-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority), and a [worse-than-average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse-than-average_effect) effect.  Each may refer to different aspects of self-image, but may even refer to the [same aspects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_illusions#Negative_counterparts)!

> For example, while college students rate themselves as more likely
>   than average to live to 70, they believe they are less likely than
>   average to live to 100. People regard themselves as above average on
>   easy tasks such as riding a bicycle but below average on difficult
>   tasks like riding a unicycle.